# select/unselect check boxes using checkbox name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have check boxes in the table created dynamically using JSF and i get the HTML output like the following,

```
 <input name="testForm:j_idt78:0:negative" id="testForm:j_idt78:0:negative" onchange='PrimeFaces.ab({s:this,e:"change",p:"testForm:j_idt78:0:negative"});' type="checkbox">
<input name="testForm:j_idt78:0:positive" id="testForm:j_idt78:0:positive" onchange='PrimeFaces.ab({s:this,e:"change",p:"testForm:j_idt78:0:positive"});' type="checkbox">
<input name="testForm:j_idt78:0:na" id="testForm:j_idt78:0:na" onchange='PrimeFaces.ab({s:this,e:"change",p:"testForm:j_idt78:0:na"});' type="checkbox">
```

i get the following exception at the console : `SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: j_idt78`

how do i select the checkbox based on the name attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use the [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
const inputId = 'testForm:j_idt78:0'
const negativeId = inputId + ':negative'
document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + negativeId + '"]').checked = true
```

```html
<input name="testForm:j_idt78:0:negative" id="testForm:j_idt78:0:negative" type="checkbox">
<input name="testForm:j_idt78:0:positive" id="testForm:j_idt78:0:positive" type="checkbox">
<input name="testForm:j_idt78:0:na" id="testForm:j_idt78:0:na" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: i get this exception now "Unable to set property 'checked' of undefined or null reference" , i am trying like the following var negativeId = inputId+":negative";
document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="+negativeId]').checked = false

Comment: It looks like you tried to concatenate the `negativeId` into the selector string, but you're missing a quote and plus sign. I've edited my answer to use a fixed version of that code.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have really saved my day.